# In python is using a for loop a correct programming technique to create objects?

Tags: python, class, list, object

Ok so basically what I'm reading data from a file and with that data I want to create an object for each line.

So something like:

```
bar = [['a','b'],['c','d']]

for foo in bar:
    foo = Class_name(list_of_arguments)
```

What would be the best technique to 'unpack' the list? Would this best be done in the initializer method of the class or would it be better to do this before the creating the object and pass the arguments in a non-list format? I ask because the lists contains information relating to the object which will be used by the class.

Also I would like each object to have a unique name, What should I do for that? Would it best be use to one of the values in the list?

Comment: What is `foo` in the for loop?  What is `list_of_arguments` what are these supposed to mean?

Comment: what is `list_of_arguments` in your code? Also, are you really trying to assign to foo, which is the iteration variable?

Comment: @S.Lott - you beat me by < 1 sec!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ... think I understand your question.  I'd probably approach it like so:

```
class myClass():
  def __init__(self, *args):
    # something here that actually uses the arguments.

data = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

objects = [myClass(*vals) for vals in data]
```

That should instantiate myClass for each set of values and return a list of the new objects, accessible by index.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Although I'm still not 100% sure how this works.

Comment: @Sheldon - Which parts? List Comprehensions are worthwhile reading if the `[x for x in y]` syntax is throwing you off. Once you've wrapped your head around those the next idea used here is that I'm unpacking the inner lists to pass them to the constructor for myClass. That's where `myClass(*vals)` comes in. HTH.